# Nodelet crashes when using pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ>, pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ>

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pcl, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Goal: Trying to detect and publish all the detected planes (coefficients) from a depth image.

Using `depth_image_proc` to compute the point-cloud. Created a similar segmentation `nodelet`, attached below. Test script works fine, where I just publish the cloud height. But, when I include `pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> vg`, `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg` Nodelet crashes at run time (compiles without issues) with the following error.

```
[ERROR] [1597300025.991310390]: Failed to load nodelet [/pcl_segmentation] of type [using_image_pipeline/pcl_segmentation] even after refreshing the cache: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type using_image_pipeline::PclSegmentationNodelet as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
[ERROR] [1597300025.991394042]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Failed to load library /home/kotaru/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libusing_image_pipeline.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/kotaru/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libusing_image_pipeline.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEE13setInputCloudERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_10PointCloudIS1_EEEE)
[FATAL] [1597300025.991807722]: Failed to load nodelet '/pcl_segmentation` of type `using_image_pipeline/pcl_segmentation` to manager `using_image_pipeline_nodelet'
[pcl_segmentation-4] process has died [pid 12564, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load using_image_pipeline/pcl_segmentation using_image_pipeline_nodelet __name:=pcl_segmentation __log:=/home/kotaru/.ros/log/00c8aa44-dd2e-11ea-aa9d-54bf64375ec6/pcl_segmentation-4.log].
log file: /home/kotaru/.ros/log/00c8aa44-dd2e-11ea-aa9d-54bf64375ec6/pcl_segmentation-4*.log
```

Can't seem to understand why that is happening, or if the implementation is wrong.

---

Plane segmentation nodelet source code,

```
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/filters/filter.h>
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/extract_clusters.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/point_cloud2_iterator.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.h>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
namespace using_image_pipeline {

class PclSegmentationNodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet {
public:
  ros::NodeHandlePtr nh_ptr_;
  boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> cloud_;
  boost::mutex connect_mutex_;
  boost::mutex mutex_;
  
  bool receivedAtLeastOnce = false;
  ros::Subscriber sub_points_;
  ros::Publisher pub_planes_;
  ros::Publisher pub_point_height_;
  std_msgs::Float32MultiArray msg_planes_;

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_raw, cloud, cloud_f;
  float leaf_size = 0.01; // 10cm 
  pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> vg;
  // pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;

  PclSegmentationNodelet(/* args */) {
    NODELET_INFO_STREAM("PclSegmentationNodelet constructor");
  }
  ~PclSegmentationNodelet() {}
  virtual void onInit();
  void pointCb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &points_msg);
  void connectCb();
  void planarSegmentation();
};

void PclSegmentationNodelet::onInit() {
  ros::NodeHandle &nh = getNodeHandle();
  nh_ptr_.reset(new ros::NodeHandle(nh));
  // cloud_.reset(new sensor_msgs::PointCloud2(nh));

  NODELET_INFO_STREAM("Initialising nodelet... [PclSegmentationNodelet]");
  ros::SubscriberStatusCallback connect_cb = boost::bind(&PclSegmentationNodelet::connectCb, this);
  boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(connect_mutex_);
  pub_planes_ = nh_ptr_->advertise<std_msgs::Float32MultiArray>("planes", 3, connect_cb, connect_cb);
  pub_point_height_ = nh_ptr_->advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("test_msg", 3, connect_cb, connect_cb);

  cloud_raw.reset(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  cloud.reset(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
}

void PclSegmentationNodelet::connectCb() {
  boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(connect_mutex_);
  sub_points_ = nh_ptr_->subscribe("points", 3, &PclSegmentationNodelet::pointCb, this);
}

void PclSegmentationNodelet::pointCb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &points_msg) {
  // boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock (mutex_);

  NODELET_DEBUG("PointCloud2 height %f", (double)points_msg->height);
  std::cout << points_msg->height << std::endl;

  // convert points_msg to pcl point cloud
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*points_msg, *cloud_raw);

  std_msgs::Float32 tmp_msg;
  tmp_msg.data = (float)cloud_raw->height;
  pub_point_height_.publish(tmp_msg);

  pub_planes_.publish(msg_planes_);
}

} // namespace using_image_pipeline

// Register as nodelet
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(using_image_pipeline::PclSegmentationNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359396/nodelet-crashes-when-using-pcl::voxelgrid%3Cpcl::pointxyz%3E,-pcl::sacsegmentation%3Cpcl::pointxyz%3E/) by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 257 on 2020-08-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-08-13**:
After some [googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&ei=aPo0X4egNNu-0PEPjoaluAE&q=undefined+symbol%3A+_ZN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEE13setInputCloudERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_10PointCloudIS1_EEEE&oq=undefined+symbol%3A+_ZN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEE13setInputCloudERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_10PointCloudIS1_EEEE&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1D-S1jjWmCvXmgBcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAqABAaABAqoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQDAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiH9MmP4pfrAhVbHzQIHQ5DCRcQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), I see that the issue is with loading `pcl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue was having dependency on PCL `find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)` in addition to `pcl_ros`.

---

Originally posted by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) with karma: 257 on 2020-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wienans](https://answers.ros.org/users/70396/wienans/) on 2021-02-19**:
Hey @praskot, i face the same problem. What did you actually change to fix it. I deleted the 'find_package(PCL REQUIRED)' in the CMakeLists.txt but it didn't helped with the issue. And i can't read more out of your answer.

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2021-02-19**:
Yeah, I just removed the line `find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)` and it worked for me. Are you facing the exact same error? Can you post your CMakelist here?

**Comment by [wienans](https://answers.ros.org/users/70396/wienans/) on 2021-02-22**:
Yes, i had the same `undefined symbol: _ZN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEE13setInputCloudERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_10PointCloudIS1_EEEE` and this was only happening in the nodelet. A normal node compiled without any problem.
But actually now i fixed it. For me i used the `velodyne_pointcloud::PointXYZIR` instead of `pcl::PointXYZ` for my code. After i changed it to `pcl::PointXYZ` the issue was fixed with and without deleting `find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)`
But thanks for your help